# Table of Contents in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, links

I'm curious to know if there's a way to create a Table of Contents within a Google Sheets. I would like to be able to set the active cell in the spreadsheet based on what cell (or contents of the cell like a hyperlink) in the TOC is clicked.

It doesn't look like there is a way to do this with hyperlinks as they only can link you to a spreadsheet but not any specific cell or sheet.

Perhaps some code could capture a cell clicked event and set the active cell accordingly?

Comment: Can you share a spreadsheet with us?

Comment: I've since discovered that hyperlinks can be used to bring you to a specific sheet by using `docs.google.com/a/DOMAIN/spreadsheet/ccc?key=YOUR_DOC_ID#gid=X` where X is the index of the sheet starting with 0 but this still is not targeted enough for what I'm trying to do. I need to get to a specific target cell. @JacobJanTuinstra Any ol spreadsheet will do. Why do you want me to share a specific one with you?

Comment: Having an example file with the expected outcome,  gives much more clarity. I for sure am better off with a shared file. It's your choice.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Here's an example -- [SpreadSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApzFHoZxz6oZdEpHVHpHU3BZRWR2YUNkNmticVBzMHc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess further progress given the time elapsed because what I think you require is very simple. Select A1 in Sheet1, click on the link icon in the menu bar, enter:

```
Sheet2!B2
```

for Link and click <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

Comment: Only took 5 years - "With this new functionality, you can create a “table of contents” for your spreadsheet..." [announcement](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/02/link-to-cell-ranges-in-google-sheets.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I made a utility that might help others who also stumble onto this question.

Like everyone else, I needed a table of contents system for Google Sheets but didn't want to have to spend time hand-making one, so I made this nifty script that'll generate one for you and also supply a sidebar that has an outline dropdown for easy navigation (similar to how outlines in other Google Docs work). All you have to do is format your sheet a bit for it, but that really doesn't take much time compared to actually hand-linking all of the cells.

You can get it here along with its source code:
https://github.com/SkyAphid/GoogleSheetsTableOfContents

Comment: Please add all the the most relevant details of the linked resource because it could be unavailable in the future for any reason.

Comment: I would, but there's not really any details to include. What I linked is just a short script to essentially perform pnuts answer for you.

Comment: If it's a short script, then add the code here.